# HTTP Status 500 - No AtmosphereHandler maps request for /j_spring_security_check

Tags: java, spring, spring-security

This gives me error, while I tried all the option regarding this question ? Regarding **Spring** project.

HTTP Status 500 - No AtmosphereHandler maps request for /j_spring_security_check
type Exception report

Message: `No AtmosphereHandler maps request for /j_spring_security_check`

Description: *The server encountered an internal error that prevented it from fulfilling this request*.

Exception:

```
    org.atmosphere.cpr.AtmosphereMappingException: No AtmosphereHandler maps request for /j_spring_security_check
        org.atmosphere.cpr.AsynchronousProcessor.map(AsynchronousProcessor.java:362)
        org.atmosphere.cpr.AsynchronousProcessor.action(AsynchronousProcessor.java:206)
        org.atmosphere.cpr.AsynchronousProcessor.suspended(AsynchronousProcessor.java:166)
        org.atmosphere.container.Tomcat7CometSupport.service(Tomcat7CometSupport.java:85)
        org.atmosphere.container.Tomcat7AsyncSupportWithWebSocket.doService(Tomcat7AsyncSupportWithWebSocket.java:59)
        org.atmosphere.container.TomcatWebSocketUtil.doService(TomcatWebSocketUtil.java:81)
        org.atmosphere.container.Tomcat7AsyncSupportWithWebSocket.service(Tomcat7AsyncSupportWithWebSocket.java:55)
        org.atmosphere.cpr.AtmosphereFramework.doCometSupport(AtmosphereFramework.java:1266)
        org.atmosphere.cpr.AtmosphereServlet.event(AtmosphereServlet.java:348)
        org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:503)
        org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:103)
        org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:950)
        org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:421)
        org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1070)
        org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:611)
        org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AprEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(AprEndpoint.java:2462)
        org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AprEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(AprEndpoint.java:2451)
        java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
        java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
        org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
        java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Note: The full stack trace of the root cause is available in the Apache Tomcat/7.0.56 logs.

Comment: I am getting same error, how did you resolve this error ?